# Is there a 1:1 correspondence between CodeDeploy applications and a Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lambda

We're investigating CodeDeploy for automating deployments of a service that is comprised of:

- Multiple Lambdas, with some triggered by SQS queues and others
  accepting HTTP requests via API Gateway
- API Gateway
- SQS queues

The question I have is actually rather simple - is there a 1:1 correspondence between a CodeDeploy application and a Lambda, or can a CodeDeploy application be comprised of multiple Lambdas? Because a release of our code base would usually impact multiple Lambdas that make up the service, so we would want to perform a rolling deployment of those Lambdas as a single action.

Comment: I haven't tried a scenario like yours, but I might suggest you could use a codepipeline that deploys to a cloudformation stack with the multiple lambdas you need and pull the code from the repo for each.